# How do I download a single song via iTunes Match in iOS 6

Tags: icloud, ios

When my iOS device doesn't have synced music but instead shows songs that are matched and available from iCloud, I've noticed there are only buttons to download groups of songs and not one song.

What is the new way for downloading just one song from the cloud to the device?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you are using the restore purchase or iTunes Match or some other function of iCloud like home sharing?

Comment: Sry, it's from iTunes Match/iCloud. I am not sure what's the difference between these two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks god. It's possible now again :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to just download one song onto an iDevice from iTunes Match right now. You can either

- request the whole album/playlist and cancel the unwanted tracks
- create one-track playlists

Both options have their drawbacks of course (especially the second one).

Comment: It's seems strange to me Apple would remove that option without alternative available

Comment: This is actually a very "Apple" move - to remove the design where you need a special download button for each track and instead depend on users learning that the download happens when you play that song. The mere act of starting to play the song queues up that track for a download. You device ends up with all the songs it can hold that you took the time to tap play and then also contains the playlists you have queued to download intentionally.

Comment: I've tried this way and it does not work. Even hour after starting to play it

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot download a single song *in the background*, the new procedure for downloading a single song is to tap on it.

Yes, this causes it to being playing as soon as enough data has been downloaded. But the download will continue even if you play something else immediately after the fact.

Comment: I've tried this way and it does not work. Even hour after starting to play it

Comment: It took about 5 seconds, but it does work for me. Were you on Wifi when you did this?

Comment: New comment because I didn't realize this before. Tapping on a song does not download it, it streams it. Very interesting. Either way, however, it does play the song.